# Way to deploy django with webpack loader with vue.js

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

while I was working on a project in django integrated with vue js via webpack.
https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader
I had a doubt about the deployment. Are there any services that allow this? For django I have always used pythonanywhere as hosting but in this case is it possible? Are there any hosting services that allow django to easily deploy with the webpack loader with vuejs?

Comment: There's a [help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Vue/#django) on PythonAnywhere for deploying Django+Vue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.